# trying to setup windows jenkins slave

Tags: windows, jenkins

I'm trying to set yo a windows jenkins slave. I go the slave connected, but I'm running into issues running builds on the slave. For example, I get the following error:

```
 FATAL: Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider
```